# Matplotlib best practices for automatically spacing out/omitting overlapping tick labels and annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've decided to use Matplotlib in one of my projects which involves having to automatically generate graphs and slapping them onto reports.

Trying to make matplotlib graphs attractive to the eye is something that's been a lot of fun - however there's still just 1 little bit I'm somewhat stuck on!

Right now, I have an issue in cases where there are tonnes of data points. The problem occurs when the x-axis ticks and the annotations overlap!

With few datapoints, the graph is very pretty:

[image: img]

However, in edge cases with very large amount of datapoints, it gets completely messed up:

[image: img2]

What I'd basically like Matplotlib to do is to use some kind of determination to make sure that no other annotation element is within range when it applies an annotation. Same concept for the x-axis ticks!

The solutions I've ruled out are things like the x-axis showing every other tick, since in some cases it's possible that even just the first 3 ticks are very close to each other!

Comment: You can use `set_xticks` and `ser_xtickslabels` to handle this issue. Look at [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_setting_ticks_and_tick_labels.htm)

Comment: Yes, that's how the x-axis tick labels are currently being applied, but the thing is I'd like to show as many data values as possible, except where the ticks overlap, so essentially each time the number ticks would be different depending on the graph being plotted.

Answer (score 1):

You can control your `xticks` using both `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` methods knowing that you're controlling just the x-axis. So, your data won't be affected

Here is an example; I've generated a list called `days` which contains all days in 2019 and the output graph:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sdate = date(2019, 1, 1)
edate = date(2019, 12, 31)
delta = edate - sdate
days = [sdate + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(delta.days+1)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(range(365))
ax.set_xticklabels(days)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

And it generated this graph which looks close enough to yours:
[image]

Now, let's see how to use `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` to handle this issue. All you need to do is to limit the vectors getting passed to these two methods like so:

```
#skips 30 items in-between
ax.set_xticks(range(0, 365, 30))
ax.set_xticklabels(days[::30])
```

And this produces this graph:
[image]

That's how you can control the ticks of your x-axis. I pretty much believe you can find a similar way to control the labels of your data points.